# current directory variable substitution in docker-compose for windows 10

Tags: docker-compose, windows-10, environment-variables

I am trying to create absolute paths in my docker-compose using variable substitution for the path up to the current directory. I pass these paths as environment variables in my container.
More precisely I try to pass it via the cd command and not via the PWD env var. It is supposed to be possible declaring the env var in the .env (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081).
Unfortunately I cannot get the substitution to work.

I tried the different approaches:

- with the declaration of the var as a environment variable in a .env OR directly in the environment list
- Running with powershell and command prompt
- using %cd% and $pwd with both shells
- escape $ and %, doubling them down with extra $ or %

Relevant piece of the docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
   jupyter:
       environment:
           - WORKING_DIR=%cd% # OR $(pwd) OR $VAR
```

and when I use the .env:

```
VAR=%cd% or ${pwd}
```

When I 'set' my environment variables in my container, it just shows the command I used (%cd%, etc) as if they were strings.

I do not quite understand where is the docker-compose formated/executed: in the shell I use to call docker-compose, in the linux image where my docker daemon runs, etc ?

EDIT:

- I tried on a MacOS version and I still have the problem ! (using adequate bash variable substitution)

Answer (score -1):

Not a complete solution, but perhaps something you can script:

If you specify DOCUMENT_ROOT as a variable in the docker compose file

```
environment:
           - WORKING_DIR=${DOCUMENT_ROOT}
```

And have an .env file in your working directory that contains
`DOCUMENT_ROOT=./`
, then you can use the local .env file by running

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml up
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file